# How to calculate the percentage of total in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, count, apache-spark, sum, apache-spark-sql

Considering the following data:

```
Name | Flag
A    | 0
A    | 1
A    | 0
B    | 0
B    | 1
B    | 1
```

I'd like to transform it to:

```
Name | Total | With Flag | Percentage
A    | 3     | 1         | 33%
B    | 3     | 2         | 66%
```

Preferably, in Spark SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example like this:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A", 0), ("A", 1), ("A", 0),
  ("B", 0), ("B", 1), ("B", 1)
)).toDF("Name", "Flag")

df.groupBy($"Name").agg(
  count("*").alias("total"),
  sum($"flag").alias("with_flag"),
  // Do you really want to truncate not for example round?
  mean($"flag").multiply(100).cast("integer").alias("percentage"))

// +----+-----+---------+----------+
// |name|total|with_flag|percentage|
// +----+-----+---------+----------+
// |   A|    3|        1|        33|
// |   B|    3|        2|        66|
// +----+-----+---------+----------+
```

or:

```scala
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("""
  SELECT name, COUNT(*) total, SUM(flag) with_flag, 
         CAST(AVG(flag) * 100 AS INT) percentage
  FROM df
  GROUP BY name""")

// +----+-----+---------+----------+
// |name|total|with_flag|percentage|
// +----+-----+---------+----------+
// |   A|    3|        1|        33|
// |   B|    3|        2|        66|
// +----+-----+---------+----------+
```

Comment: @LokeshKumarP `df.groupBy($"Name").agg(avg(($"Flag" > 50).cast("int")))`

Comment: Can you please put in plain english on what the above statement does?

Comment: @LokeshKumarP `($"Flag" > 50).cast("int")` creates a `{0, 1}` indicator variable. And the rest is just plain average.